# Clearing two-dimensional array

Tags: vb.net

I am using a two-dimensional array of 10 elements, but my code is extremely slow.

```
Dim myArray As String(,) 
For i=0 to 100
   'Clear Array. (This line is really slow)
   myArray = New String(,) {{"", ""}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}, _
   {"", ""}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}}

   'Populate array
   fillArray(myArray) 

   'Do stuff with array
   useArray(myArray)
Next i
```

I create a new empty array with every iteration of the for loop. Is there a way I can use the same array but just clear it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't vb.net have a way to quickly create 2 dimensional arrays? It was something like:

```
Dim rectArray(10, 10) As String
```

Then you can populate as usual:

```
Dim rectArray(,) As String = {{'', '', '' ....etc
```

some reading that might help - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: You're so right! After a bit of research it turns out the syntax is actually arr = New String(9, 1) {}. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear what you're using your array for, but you might want to look into using a collection instead.

As far as clearing the array is concerned, look into using [Array.Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx).

Comment: Note, though, that `Array.Clear` will set the elements to their default value -- which, in the case of strings, is `Nothing` (`null` for the C# folks).

Comment: The array gets populated and then its contents gets read elsewhere. That bit's not important though. I'm just illustrating the point that I need to clear the array whilst keeping its structure.

Comment: What's the advantage of collections over arrays?